# Why is Copy a supertrait of ZeroCopy?

Tags: anchor

This is the definition of `ZeroCopy` in anchor:

```
pub trait ZeroCopy: Discriminator + Copy + Clone + Zeroable + Pod { }
```

I know the purpose/usecase of `#[account(zero_copy)]` and `AccountLoader<'info, T>`. I just don't understand why a `ZeroCopy` should at least be a `Copy`? I want zero copy feature because the account is very large (e.g., over 10 KB). But if the account is very large, why is `Copy` required? I mean, it's ridiculous to **copy** (instead of move) a variable of type that is over 10 KB size.

I've read the zero copy example [here](https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-examples/tree/main/account-constraints/zero) provided by Anchor team. There's a `DataAccount` which is marked as `#[account(zero_copy)]`, shown as following:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct DataAccount {
    data: [u8; 10240],
}
```

I've run `cargo expand` to examine the code after the attribute macro is expanded:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct DataAccount {
    data: [u8; 10240],
}
const _: fn() = || {
    #[allow(clippy::missing_const_for_fn)]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    fn check() {
        fn assert_impl<T: ::bytemuck::Zeroable>() {}
        assert_impl::<[u8; 10240]>();
    }
};
unsafe impl ::bytemuck::Zeroable for DataAccount {}
const _: fn() = || {
    #[doc(hidden)]
    struct TypeWithoutPadding([u8; ::core::mem::size_of::<[u8; 10240]>()]);
    let _ = ::core::mem::transmute::<DataAccount, TypeWithoutPadding>;
};
const _: fn() = || {
    #[allow(clippy::missing_const_for_fn)]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    fn check() {
        fn assert_impl<T: ::bytemuck::Pod>() {}
        assert_impl::<[u8; 10240]>();
    }
};
unsafe impl ::bytemuck::Pod for DataAccount {}
#[automatically_derived]
impl DataAccount {}
#[automatically_derived]
impl ::core::marker::Copy for DataAccount {}
#[automatically_derived]
impl ::core::clone::Clone for DataAccount {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> DataAccount {
        let _: ::core::clone::AssertParamIsClone<[u8; 10240]>;
        *self
    }
}
#[automatically_derived]
impl anchor_lang::ZeroCopy for DataAccount {}
#[automatically_derived]
impl anchor_lang::Discriminator for DataAccount {
    const DISCRIMINATOR: [u8; 8] = [85, 240, 182, 158, 76, 7, 18, 233];
}
#[automatically_derived]
impl anchor_lang::AccountDeserialize for DataAccount {
    fn try_deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        if buf.len() < [85, 240, 182, 158, 76, 7, 18, 233].len() {
            return Err(
                anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode::AccountDiscriminatorNotFound.into(),
            );
        }
        let given_disc = &buf[..8];
        if &[85, 240, 182, 158, 76, 7, 18, 233] != given_disc {
            return Err(
                anchor_lang::error::Error::from(anchor_lang::error::AnchorError {
                        error_name: anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode::AccountDiscriminatorMismatch
                            .name(),
                        error_code_number: anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode::AccountDiscriminatorMismatch
                            .into(),
                        error_msg: anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode::AccountDiscriminatorMismatch
                            .to_string(),
                        error_origin: Some(
                            anchor_lang::error::ErrorOrigin::Source(anchor_lang::error::Source {
                                filename: "programs/example/src/lib.rs",
                                line: 58u32,
                            }),
                        ),
                        compared_values: None,
                    })
                    .with_account_name("DataAccount"),
            );
        }
        Self::try_deserialize_unchecked(buf)
    }
    fn try_deserialize_unchecked(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        let data: &[u8] = &buf[8..];
        let account = anchor_lang::__private::bytemuck::from_bytes(data);
        Ok(*account)
    }
}
#[automatically_derived]
impl anchor_lang::Owner for DataAccount {
    fn owner() -> Pubkey {
        crate::ID
    }
}
```

Surprisingly found the `AccountDeserialize` trait is implemented for `DataAccount`! In my understanding, when we use `AccountLoader<'info, T>`, the account data won't be deserialized into a stack variable. Instead, the account data is simply reinterpreted (via `bytemuck` crate) as a `DataAccount` type (therefore the term "zero copy"). This is also exactly what `load` and `load_mut` do (refer to [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/src/accounts/account_loader.rs#L153-L190)). So why is `AccountDeserialize` implemented? Since we'll never deserialize such large bunch of data...

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question after some research.

The reason why `Copy` is a supertrait of `ZeroCopy` is because `Copy` is a supertrait of `Pod`, and `Pod` is a supertrait of `ZeroCopy`.

But why is `Copy` a supertrait of `Pod`? This is not special to Solana development, since it's all about the bytemuck crate. I've asked this question on stackoverflow main site. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78134616/why-is-copy-a-supertrait-of-pod-in-the-bytemuck-crate).